# fatal error: Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object in magento

Tags: collection, magento-1.6

I am trying to get a collection of objects of a table of our database. Unfortunately the following code was leading to an error.

my code is

```
  <?php

class Ics_EasyLife_Block_Template extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function methodblock()
    {

        //on initialize la variable
        $retour='';

        $collection = Mage::getModel('easylife/easylife')->getCollection()->setOrder('id_ics_easylife','asc');

        foreach($collection as $data)
        {
            $retour .= $data->getData('nom').' '.$data->getData('prenom').' '.$data->getData('telephone').'<br />';
        }

        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess('Cool Ca marche !!');
        return $retour;
    }
}
```

//config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ics_EasyLife>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Ics_EasyLife>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <icscontroller>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Ics_EasyLife</module>
                    <frontName>display</frontName>
                </args>
            </icscontroller>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <easylife>
                    <file>easylife.xml</file>
                </easylife>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <easylife>
                <class>Ics_EasyLife_Block</class>
            </easylife>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <easylife>
                <class>Ics_EasyLife_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>easylife_resource</resourceModel>
            </easylife>
            <easylife_resource>
                <class>Ics_EasyLife_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <easylife>
                        <table>ics_test</table>
                    </easylife>
                </entities>
            </easylife_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <easylife_write>
                <connection>core_write</connection>
            </easylife_write>
            <easylife_read>
                <connection>core_read</connection>
            </easylife_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

//Model->Easylife.php

```
<?php

class Ics_EasyLife_Model_Easylife extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('easylife/easylife');
    }
}
```

//Model->Resource->Easylife.php

```
<?php
class Ics_EasyLife_Model_Resource_Easylife extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('easylife/easylife','id_easylife');
    }
}

?>
```

//Model->Resource->Easylife->Collection.php

```
<?php
class Ics_EasyLife_Model_Resource_Easylife_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('easylife/easylife');
    }
}
```

//sql->install-0.0.1.php

```
<?php


$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("

--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('easylife')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('easylife')} (
'id_easylife' INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
'nom' VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
'prenom' VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
'telephone' VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY ('id_easylife')
);ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

");

$installer->endSetup();
```

can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you also post part of your config.xml involved with the (resource) models and maybe your directory structure. The error basically tells us that `Mage::getModel('easylife/easylife')` doesn't return a valid class

Comment: hi sander,see updated my code

Comment: Quick question, does the file `Ics/Easylife/Model/Easylife.php` actually exist?

Comment: ok I updated but it's returning same error.

Comment: that might b the problem, getModel is not getting the model.

Comment: Check the answers for my update :)

Comment: Hey Manoj, did you get any further with resolving the question?

Comment: Hi sander, I resolved the same day but, I forget the accept this thread. thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error basically tells us that  Mage::getModel('easylife/easylife')  doesn't return a valid class. Please make sure the file `Ics/Easylife/Model/Easylife.php` exists and looks somewhat like the code posted below, this should give you access to the resource model.

```
class Ics_Easylife_Model_Easylife extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
   public function _construct()
   {
      parent::_construct();
      $this->_init('easylife/easylife');
   }
}
```

If that doesn't work I'd advice you to check out [this wikipage](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table) which clearly outlines what you need to do on using collections.

Comment: hi sander, see my update code, it's given error. Could you provide solution?

Comment: Please use the wikipage I've provided in my answer to build your extension. I've used it before and it works, I'm 100% sure of that. Also it's best to post your error in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Check your module's Model properly there must something wrong. do you have properly structured collection class in your module's model ?

Comment: hi sarvagya, see my update code, it's given error. Could you provide solution?

Comment: Just before the line `$collection = Mage::getModel('easylife/easylife')->getCollection()->setOrder('id_ics_easylife','asc');
` put this and check it prints your model class name correctly. `echo get_class(Mage::getModel('easylife/easylife'));exit;`

Comment: try Su123 method you will be able to know your class exists or not.

Comment: I create my own module and call  `var_dump(get_class(Mage::getModel('fastsearchhint/product')));exit;`
but it return false

Answer (score 2):

Sometime if you try to un-insall any extension (for me its was 'Mgt_DeveloperToolbar') by manually delete all related files but still you need to clear data from 'core_resource' table.

Comment: core_resource table have entries for the modules which have setup resources so whenever you install any extension it checks inside the core_resource if it is already present. If you are re-installing extension you will get issue if the same extension with same version is already present inside core_resource table.

Answer (score 1):

In case you try to un-insall any extension by manually delete all, need to clear all cache. If you are using redis cache, please try in command line:

```
Nguyens-MacBook-Pro:~ nguyende$ redis-cli flushall
```