# Fatal error: Call to a member function setOrder()

Tags: magento-1, error, collection, resource-model, create

I have few problems when try make a plugin.

This is my code:

**Mibloque.php

```
class Uniagro_Tpv_Block_Mibloque extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function methodblock()
    {
        //return "informations about my block !!" ;
        //on initialize la variable
        $retour='';
        /* we are doing the query to select all elements of the pfay_test table (thanks to our model test/test and we sort them by id_pfay_test */
     $collection = Mage::getModel('tpv/tpv')->getCollection()->setOrder('id','asc');
         /* then, we check the result of the query and with the function getData() */
        foreach($collection as $data)
        {
             $retour .= $data->getData('banco').' '.$data->getData('codigotienda')
                     .' '.$data->getData('url').'<br />';
         }
         //i return a success message to the user thanks to the Session.
         Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess('Cool Ca marche !!');
         return $retour;      
    }
}
```

** config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
     <modules>
        <Uniagro_Tpv>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Uniagro_Tpv>
     </modules>
     <frontend>
       <routers>
          <routeurfrontend>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>Uniagro_Tpv</module>
                 <frontName>pasarela</frontName> <!-- sirve a modo de ruta del modulo [...]/index y va al modulo -->
              </args>
           </routeurfrontend>
       </routers>
       <layout>
            <updates>
                <tpv>
                    <file>uniagropasarela.xml</file>
                </tpv>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <tpv>
                 <class>Uniagro_Tpv_Block</class>
            </tpv>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <tpv>
                <class>Uniagro_Tpv_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>tpv_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </tpv>
            <tpv_mysql4>
                <class>Uniagro_Tpv_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <tpv>
                        <table>uniagro_datosPasarela</table>
                    </tpv>
                </entities>
            </tpv_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <!-- connection to write -->
            <tpv_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </tpv_write>
            <!-- connection to read -->
            <tpv_read>
              <connection>
                 <use>core_read</use>
              </connection>
            </tpv_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

** model/Tpv.php

```
class Uniagro_Tpv_Model_Tpv extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
     public function _construct()
     {
         parent::_construct();
         $this->_init('tpv/tpv');
     }
}
```

** model/Mysql4/Tpv.php

```
class Uniagro_Tpv_Mysql4_Tpv extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('tpv/tpv', 'id');
    }
}
```

I'm try some solutions (for example this [[fatal error: Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object in magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8774/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-getcollection-on-a-non-object-in-magent][1])

[1]: [fatal error: Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object in magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8774/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-getcollection-on-a-non-object-in-magent) ) but always send my the same error "Fatal error: Call to a member function setOrder()"

And i review my bd and have the column to order ('id')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add model collection class and try

```
class Uniagro_Tpv_Mysql4_Tpv_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract{
    public function _construct(){
        $this->_init('tpv/tpv');
    }
}
```

**Edit**
*(As result of the comments)*:

The Problem was the wrong named/placed class `Uniagro_Tpv_Mysql4_Tpv` which belongs into the `Model` area so it has to be `Uniagro_Tpv_Model_Mysql4_Tpv`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i try to put this code but, have the same error :S

Comment: have you created the table

Comment: Yes, I have the table in my bd and exists the column to the order ('id'), if need more code i can write

Comment: `class Uniagro_Tpv_Mysql4_Tpv extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract` missing `model` class, (ie) `Uniagro_Tpv_Mysql4_Tpv` to `Uniagro_Tpv_Model_Mysql4_Tpv`

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help! I found it my error....the problem is the PHP for Mysql4/Tpv/Collection.php...i delete this file and I write again and success! Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('tpv/tpv')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->order('main_table.id ASC');
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but don't work...This code give me the error " Fatal error: Call to a member function getSelect() on a non-object"

Comment: This won't work because in the OP's case `getCollection()` returns null.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help, I found my problem...its for the Collection file, i delete this and make again and it's Ok! Thanks again!